# When do we get multiple changes in ListChangeListener.Change<E>?

Tags: java, javafx

From [JavaFX ListChangeListener.Change API](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html#next())

> public abstract boolean next()
>
> Goes to the next change. The Change instance, in its initial state, is
>   invalid and requires a call to next() before calling other methods.
>   The first next() call will make this object represent the first
>   change.

So, if we have the first change, we can have the second etc. Now, consider the following code:

```
public class NewMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        ObservableList<String> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList("Z", "Y", "X");
        list.addListener((ListChangeListener)(event) -> {
            while(event.next()) {
                System.out.println("Added:" +  event.wasAdded());
                System.out.println("Permutated:" +  event.wasPermutated());
                System.out.println("Removed:" +  event.wasRemoved());
                System.out.println("Replaced:" +  event.wasReplaced());
                System.out.println("Updated:" +  event.wasUpdated());
            }
        });
        System.out.println("REPLACING");
        list.set(0, "W");
        System.out.println("\nCLEARING");
        list.clear();
    }
}
```

This is the output:

```
REPLACING
Added:true
Permutated:false
Removed:true
Replaced:true
Updated:false

CLEARING
Added:false
Permutated:false
Removed:true
Replaced:false
Updated:false
```

If one change for replacing is clear - `replaced + removed + added` then how to explain that when we do clear we anyway get one change. Explain please, when we get multiple changes in ListChangeListener.Change?

Comment: I'm confused on what you are asking. Could you possibly reword your question?

Comment: @SizableShrimp I believe the OP is wondering in what circumstances will `ListChangeListener.Change.next()` return `true` more than once (without a call to `reset()`). In other words, when will a `while (change.next())` loop iterate two or more times.

Comment: I guess this could happen for bulk operations on certain implementations of `ObservableList` - have you tried [`SortedList`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.base/javafx/collections/transformation/SortedList.html), for example - I guess `addAll()` might trigger multiple inserts at various positions within the original list, for example.

Comment: @Hulk after addAll() we also get one change - I've just checked.

Comment: well, you could have gone through all operations defined on a list and check what you get, then you would have a complete list of when that happens _from the core implementation_ - custom impl might do better: f.i. I have a custom impl that enhances FilteredList to fire a fine-grained notification on replacing the predicate such that a tableView can keep its selection state. the important part is not _which-does-it-when_ but to keep in mind that you have to _expect_ notification with multiple parts and handle them as doc'ed in the api

Comment: @kleopatra The point of this question to understand the principle when we get multiple changes.

Comment: yeah sure, but you just could have tried - the result would have been more complete than the accepted answer and you would have gained experience hands-on how with list change notifications ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A single change can be responsible for modifying a range of values (which you can determine by checking the `from` and `to` properties of the `Change`). Usually `ObservableList`s try to trigger the least number of partial changes possible and for clear this is a remove change with a single part with a `from` value of 0 and a `to` value equal to the size of the list before calling `clear()`.

The exact changes triggered are up to the `ObservableList` implementation, but the implementation available via `ObservableListBase` does a good job at grouping modifications. This class is the superclass of many of the `ObservableList` implementations used.

There's little that triggers multi-part changes in a single event in the standard `ObservableList` implementations, but `retainAll` can do this (*thanks* @kleopatra for mentioning this):

```
ObservableList<Integer> ol = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    ol.add(i);
}

ol.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer> event) -> {
    System.out.println("new change----------------------------------------------");
    while(event.next()) {
        System.out.println("Added:" +  event.wasAdded());
        System.out.println("Permutated:" +  event.wasPermutated());
        System.out.println("Removed:" +  event.wasRemoved());
        System.out.println("Replaced:" +  event.wasReplaced());
        System.out.println("Updated:" +  event.wasUpdated());
    }
});
ol.retainAll(1, 3, 5, 7, 9);
```

**output:**

```
new change----------------------------------------------
Added:false
Permutated:false
Removed:true
Replaced:false
Updated:false
Added:false
Permutated:false
Removed:true
Replaced:false
Updated:false
Added:false
Permutated:false
Removed:true
Replaced:false
Updated:false
Added:false
Permutated:false
Removed:true
Replaced:false
Updated:false
Added:false
Permutated:false
Removed:true
Replaced:false
Updated:false
```

Any `ObservableList` implementation can define new operations that group do multiple changes that result in a single notification of the listeners though. The simplest way of implementing this is using `ObservableListBase`'s `beginChange` and `endChange` methods:

```
class Ol extends ModifiableObservableListBase<Integer> {

    private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(2, 4, 6, 8));

    @Override
    public Integer get(int index) {
        return list.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int size() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    protected void doAdd(int index, Integer element) {
        list.add(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doSet(int index, Integer element) {
        return list.set(index, element);
    }

    @Override
    protected Integer doRemove(int index) {
        return list.remove(index);
    }

    public void modify() {
        if (size() < 4) {
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        beginChange();
        set(0, 3);
        set(3, 7);
        endChange();
    }

}
```

`modify()` triggers 2 replacement changes, if successfull.